# The preview of FB.ui feed method is not same when posted to the wall

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk, fb.ui

I have created a simple APP and when I post the result to the wall by using 'FB.ui()' 'feed' method the resultant post on the is not same as the preview shown. The post on the wall truncated some lines from the preview. Again the see more link also is not there.Now my Question is Why this mismatch ??

The code for post to wall fb.ui method

```
            method: 'feed',
            link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/justflop/',
            actions: [ { name: 'Flop of the Week', link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/justflop/'}],
            properties: [
            { text: 'FLOP Friend :'+fr, href: 'https://www.facebook.com/<?php echo $friends[0]["uid"]; ?>'},
            { text: 'FLOP Lover :'+lo, href: 'https://www.facebook.com/<?php echo $lover[0]["uid"]; ?>'},
            { text: 'FLOP Enemy :'+en, href: 'https://www.facebook.com/<?php echo $enemy[0]["uid"]; ?>'}
            ],
        },
        function (response) {
          // If response is null the user canceled the dialog
          if (response != null) {
            logResponse(response);
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use 3 "{text: ...}" params.
Use Name, Caption, and Description: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

When you use unsupported params or multiple params with the same key, you cannot expect the story to render predictably.

Comment: I want to publish the name of three friends. For that purpose I used the properties parameter which appear as link in the preview of the Feed Dialog but when shared to post to wall it shows only the first two link parameters of properties. 

Name, Caption and Description will only give the information about the link parameter.

Comment: please see this code from where I got the code

http://www.fbrell.com/saved/8274761e2a8952ce8c1e431146d37d2d